# REST: nested resource url when you don't want the parent ID visible

Tags: rest, routes, restful-url

I [read](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/) that the route for getting a nested resource in REST should look like this

> `/articles/:articleId/comments`

The owner (`:articleId`) of the child resource will be visible.

But what if you have an owner that you don't want the client to know about?

For example, let's say I have an app where users have anonymous posts. I wouldn't want other users to see the client fetching the post by `/users/123/post/321` because users could identify who wrote the post from the id and it wouldn't be anonymous.

Is the id necessary? Is it ok to instead do `/users/posts/321` if all posts have a unique id?

Comment: It's completely up to you how to structure the url. There are no real rules, just suggestions. Do what makes sense for your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no actual requirements for the URL format.  It can be whatever you'd like it to be.

If it were me, I would use simply `/posts/321` and leave `users` out of it, since a particular user isn't specified in your URL at all.  I think that's the clearest way to handle it in your case.